# If d1 & d2 are matrics then 1/4d1 + 3/4d2 is metric or not.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ be matrics on a non empty set $X$. 
Then $$\frac{1}{4}d_{1}+ \frac{3}{4}d_{2}$$ metric on $X$ ?

Actually I am confused in "Symmetry" property of metrics. 
$$\frac{1}{4}d_{1}+ \frac{3}{4}d_{2}\ne\frac{1}{4}d_{2}+ \frac{3}{4}d_{1}$$

Is it correct? Hence its not a metric.

Comment: I am confused in symmetric property

Answer (score 2):

[Not an answer...but possibly helpful]

Recall the symmetry property of metrics: if $d$ is a metric, then for all $a,b \in X$ a non-empty set we have $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$.

Above, I presume that when you define the "new" metric you intend something like:
$$d_3(a,b) = \frac{1}{4} d_1(a,b) + \frac{3}{4} d_2(a,b).$$

So to test for $d_3$'s symmetry, we simply need to verify that $d_3(a,b) = d_3(b,a)$. Since we are given that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics, then we have

$$ d_3(a,b) = \frac{1}{4} d_1(a,b) + \frac{3}{4} d_2(a,b) \\
= \frac{1}{4} d_1(b,a) + \frac{3}{4} d_2(b,a) \\
= d_3(b,a).
$$

So altogether, $d_3$ has the symmetry property required to be a metric. However, you would still need to show that $d_3$ has the other properties (non-negativity, identity of indiscernibles, and the triangle inequality) to prove that $d_3$ is indeed a metric.

Comment: Helpfull!! Thanks Dear!!